# Why did git stop tracking local changes?

Tags: git

Git suddenly stopped tracking ALL changes on my branch locally. If i create a new branch from this one, modified changes will be found. But if I modify files, rename files, etc.. Git continues to state no changes have been made when running `git status`. .gitignore and .git/../exclude are fine because in the new branch everything works ok. Im not sure if I can force a commit, running git diff doesnt even return anything when I try to compare it to the remote branch its tracking, so `git pull` doesnt do anything either. Any and all help is appreciated

Running on Windows
Git version 2.24

`git ls-files` shows all files

Update: There was formerly a nested repo that was pushed up. Now it seems that any changes made inside of this file are not being tracked but changes outside the formerly-nested repo, still inside the main repo, are being tracked.

Comment: What operating system are you on?  What version of Git are you using?  Have you invoked `git update-index` with any of its various options (e.g., `--skip-worktree`)?  What does your `.gitignore` contain on the problem branch?  Does `git ls-files` show you the list of files you expect to be tracked?

Comment: .gitignore contains migration files and venv dir. The last thing I invoked was git branch -m  <new_name> to change the name of my branch. I updated my question though and I now realize that the main problem is the dir that was a former repo. No changes within that file are being tracked, and I've already removed the .git directory from this directory

Answer (score 0):

So I ruled out the untracked files "on-change" were in the formerly nested repo. Once i removed the .git files I needed to run `git rm --cahced <dir_name>` and then re add the directory. It works normally now

Comment: What this means is: you *had* a submodule. You still had it, even though you thought you had un-done it, because your superproject's index still listed the gitlink for the submodule. The `git rm --cached dir` removed the gitlink, erasing the submodule-ness.